# Updating an entity's type in TypeORM single table inheritance

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, single-table-inheritance

Is there any way to change an inheriting entity's type (in the DB) to a different entity type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert entity with `uid` from `OldType` to `NewType`:

```
await em.update(OldType, { uid: uid }, {[entityTypeColumnName]: 'NewType'})
```